# detect the side of a div and hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am using this example http://jsfiddle.net/MJTkk/2/ in order to find where the cursor is(left or right in my example). i also have two images and i want the second.png to hover over the other smoothly but to hover on the direction of the cursor(follow the cursor).

```
<div class="box" id="box" style="margin:100px 0px 0px 100px">
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <div class="under_div"></div>   
        <div class="over_div"></div>    
     </a>   
</div>

.box {
position:relative;
width:100px;
height:100px;
}
.under_div
 {
    background-size: 100px 100px;   
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-image:url(http://s30.postimg.org/dd01lyrjx/first.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top right;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.over_div
{
    background-size: 100px 100px;   
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-image:url(http://s21.postimg.org/wjrhdklar/second.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: top left;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.box:hover .over_div
{
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

i implement this http://jsfiddle.net/9yj8or2z/1/ because i do not know how to explain it correctly. sorry for my english.

i see that it does not work properly and the div moves when hover for some reason. if someone could help i will appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove your `css` code in the `jquery` function completely for `.under_div`

i updated your [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9yj8or2z/3/)  if this is what you want to achieve.

**EDIT** i updated the fiddle once again. you got to give the over_div if it's coming from the right (so in the `else` tag in the first function) a `position: absolute; right: 0; left: auto;`  and in the second function `right: auto; left: 0;`

[FIDDLE NO 2 BOTH DIRECTIONS WORKING](http://jsfiddle.net/9yj8or2z/5/)

ask if you got any further questions, but this should be it!

Comment: when you hover(first time) from the right side, it slide from left and it is not correct or if hover left and then go and hover from right it does the same..  is there any way to fix it?

Comment: updated the fiddle, now it's working from both sides!

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is that the grey png is moving too on hover, I think that this solution works.

```js
$(function() {
    $("#box").hover(function(e) {
        var el_pos = $(this).offset();
        var edge = closestEdge(e.pageX - el_pos.left, e.pageY - el_pos.top, $(this).width(), $(this).height());
    
    $('.under_div').css({
     "left":"0",
     "width":"100px",
     "background-position":"100% 0%"
    });
    
    $('.over_div').css({
     "left":"0",
     "width":"0px",
     "background-position":"0% 0%"
    });
    
    if(edge=='left')
   {
    $('.over_div').css({
       "left":"0",
       "width":"100px",
       "background-position":"0% 0%"
       });
   }
  
  else
   {
    $('.over_div').css({
       "left":"0px",
       "width":"100px",
       "background-position":"100% 0%"
       });
   }
    
    }, function(e) {
        var el_pos = $(this).offset();
        var edge = closestEdge(e.pageX - el_pos.left, e.pageY - el_pos.top, $(this).width(), $(this).height());
  
  if(edge=='left')
   {
    $('.over_div').css({
       "left":"0px",
       "width":"0px",
       "background-position":"0% 0%"
       });
   }
  
  else
   {
    $('.over_div').css({
       "left":"100px",
       "width":"0px",
       "background-position":"100% 0%"
       });
   }
        
    });
});

function closestEdge(x,y,w,h) {
        var leftEdgeDist = distMetric(x,y,0,h/2);
        var rightEdgeDist = distMetric(x,y,w,h/2);
  var min = Math.min(leftEdgeDist,rightEdgeDist);
        switch (min) {
            case leftEdgeDist:
                return "left";
            case rightEdgeDist:
                return "right";
        }
}
  
function distMetric(x,y,x2,y2) {
    var xDiff = x - x2;
    var yDiff = y - y2;
    return (xDiff * xDiff) + (yDiff * yDiff);
}
```

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.under_div {
  background-size: 100px 100px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(http://s30.postimg.org/dd01lyrjx/first.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top right;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.over_div {
  background-size: 100px 100px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(http://s21.postimg.org/wjrhdklar/second.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top left;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.box:hover .over_div {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" id="box" style="margin:100px 0px 0px 100px">
  <a href="#" target="_blank">
    <div class="under_div"></div>
    <div class="over_div"></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: it is not the only problem, it does not follow the movement of the cursor when you reload and the go from the right it slide left.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed some issues with it: http://jsfiddle.net/9yj8or2z/2/

By adding `left: 0;` and `width: 0px;` to CSS, and also adding `overflow:hidden;`, I could fix that the gray box was moving at the beginning wrongly, but still animates.

I hope this is what you were looking for :)

Comment: it still animates and when you change sides it does not follow the movement of the cursor